# Textarea value count length jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, textarea, counter

I think i'm missing something or have a silly error. I'm trying to get the counter going for textarea & for some reason length of textarea value is always zero. Here is my same code for View:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Description, new { @maxlength = "4000", @onkeyup = "countChar(this)" })
@Html.Label("", " ", new { @id = "lblcount" })
```

my corresponding javascript is:

```
function countChar(val) {
    var max = 4000;
    var len = $("#txtDescription").val().length;
    if (len >= max) {
        $('#lblcount').text(' you have reached the limit');
        $('#lblcount').attr("class", "lblCountRed");
    } else {
        var ch = max - len;
        $('#lblcount').text(ch + ' characters left');
        $('#lblcount').attr("class", "lblCountGreen");
    }
};
```

The above code always sets label text to "4000 characters left" irrespective of number of characters I type inside textarea.

Comment: Where does it say WFRequest_ReqName is the ID of the textarea? Can you post the rendered html too?

Comment: The `id` of this element would match the name of the property of the model which in this case is `Description`, not `txtDescription`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would really **NOT** advice you to use inline JavaScript but here is what the function should be:

```
function countChar( elem ) {
    var max = 4000,
        len = elem.value.length,
        lbl = $('#lblcount');
    if(len >= max) {
        lbl.text(' you have reached the limit')
        .addClass("lblCountRed").removeClass('lblCountGreen');
    } else {
        var ch = max - len;
        lbl.text(ch + ' characters left')
        .addClass("lblCountGreen").removeClass('lblCountRed');
    }
}
```

If you wanted to accomplish this without inline JavaScript, you would:

- remove `@onkeyup = "countChar(this)"`
- then use the following code:

-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Description").on('keyup', function() {
        var max = 4000,
            len = this.value.length,
            lbl = $('#lblcount');
        if(len >= max) {
            lbl.text(' you have reached the limit')
            .addClass("lblCountRed").removeClass('lblCountGreen');
        } else {
            var ch = max - len;
            lbl.text(ch + ' characters left')
            .addClass("lblCountGreen").removeClass('lblCountRed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: len = $.trim( elem.value ).length; --> this works :) thanks a lot

Comment: Great! Glad you found this helpful. I have removed `$.trim( )` since spaces may be part of the user's text as the user types. `var x=1, y=3, z=50;` is syntactically correct code; it is equivalent to `var x=1; var y=3; var z=50;`.

Answer (score 0):

You used wrong selector. Your textarea ID is `Description` but you used `txtDescription`. You should use

```
var len = $("#Description").val().length;
```

instead of

```
var len = $("#txtDescription").val().length;
```